# Adding List to List in flutter

Tags: flutter, list

I am having a trouble with adding List to a List

```
void save() {
    List list = [_a, _b, _c, _d]
    historyDb.historyList.add(list);
    historyDb.updateHistory();
    _isSave = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Value _d is a List.

Values are from the provider. When save data one is fine for example i getting [[a, b, c, [1, 2, 3]]]
but when i save data second time first entry is looking as second so i have everywhere the same data.

I tried to clear the List before new data with list.clear() and list = []

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `spread` operator to take all the elements from different lists and then add them together in a new list. Ex:

```
List list = [..._a, ..._b, ..._c, ...d];
```

So it will take all elements from list `a,b,c,d` and then create a new list with those items.